# Submit Form that is Dynamicly inserted into the page using jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Form that is generated with JavaScript and then inserted into a popup Modal window.

My form HTML is not generated or inserted into the page until well after the DOM has generated the whole page (it is triggered from a Socket post event which then makes my popup open and inserts the HTML for this form)

There can also be multiple Forms inserted into the page so not just 1.

Here is an example of the form code that is generated and inserted into the page...

```
<form action="/" id="logCallForm" class="logCallForm">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
        <br><input type="hidden" name="qmsId" value="1c885762-27d5-58ef-9f95-527ae750c9be">
        <input type="hidden" name="dateTime" value="2013-11-07 01:05:19">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Call">
</form>
```

Now below is some JavaScript that is already running on the same page, my goal is to be able to POST these Forms using AJAX.  Right now it does not seem to detect the code though as when I hit the submit button, it loads a new page instead of trying to submit through AJAX.

Please help me?  I am pretty sure it has something to do with my Forms being added after the page has been loaded already?

```
$(function () {

    $('.logCallForm').on('submit', function (e) {

        var url = '/custom/modules/nam_call_logger/call_server.php';

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               // qmsId dateTime subject
               success: function(data)
               {
                   alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               }
        });
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try subscribing in a *lively* manner:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.logCallForm', function (e) {
```

Basically this will subscribe to the `submit` event of elements that match the selector, even if those elements do not yet exist at the time you are making the subscription (a.k.a the DOM load of the page). It will *listen* for future elements that might be added to the DOM and which match the selector.